# Heroku nodejs deployment just wont work

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I am deploying this git repo https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/hex-chat to heroku and it just keeps giving me application error. I am using the Github manual deployment feature in Heroku to deploy my app.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious because I am going crazy here!

My Heroku URL is https://hex-chat.herokuapp.com/

This is what my log trail is returning:

```
2015-01-13T05:41:33.331894+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-01-13T05:41:33.334277+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2015-01-13T05:41:33.331172+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2015-01-13T05:41:33.334057+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-01-13T05:41:33.333928+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details
 can be found in:
2015-01-13T05:41:34.099075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-01-13T05:41:34.099733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-01-13T05:41:34.086723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-13T05:41:35.923333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2015-01-13T05:41:37.057740+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.141404+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.132783+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-01-13T05:41:37.057738+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-01-13T05:41:37.057714+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.133012+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-01-13T05:41:37.131798+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136260+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:280:25)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.132333+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2015-01-13T05:41:37.147468+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! hex-chat@0.0.1 start: `nod
e ./bin/www`
2015-01-13T05:41:37.147851+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-01-13T05:41:37.147970+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the hex-chat@0.0
.1 start script.
2015-01-13T05:41:37.147690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2015-01-13T05:41:37.148335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the hex-chat package,
2015-01-13T05:41:37.148453+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-01-13T05:41:37.057736+00:00 app[web.1]: > hex-chat@0.0.1 start /app
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136255+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'ws'
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136264+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136258+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:338:15)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149074+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149152+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-01-13T05:41:37.153423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149860+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/.heroku/node
/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149424+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls hex-chat
2015-01-13T05:41:37.150657+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149318+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via
:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136268+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
56:26)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136266+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app
.js:1:85)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136262+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:36
4:17)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.150135+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149704+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2015-01-13T05:41:37.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2015-01-13T05:41:37.149696+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2015-01-13T05:41:37.150942+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-01-13T05:41:37.153221+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details
 can be found in:
2015-01-13T05:41:37.153011+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-01-13T05:41:37.150392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136272+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:3
2)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136270+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:474:10)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136276+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:36
4:17)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.136274+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:312:12)
2015-01-13T05:41:37.879008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-01-13T05:41:37.853229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-13T05:41:43.304563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=hex-chat.herokuapp.com request_id=8d909271-1569-4
1e4-9942-31df329a0892 fwd="192.0.196.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byt
es=
2015-01-13T05:41:44.449552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=hex-chat.herokuapp.com request_id=c3f41f72-7bfa-4
59e-8566-9f2a1a2cd2ea fwd="192.0.196.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byt
es=
2015-01-13T05:44:52.744422+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by lucamatthewd
ecaprio@gmail.com
2015-01-13T05:44:52.744422+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2c5ed86 by lucamatthewdecap
rio@gmail.com
2015-01-13T05:44:52.990045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-01-13T05:44:55.162193+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2015-01-13T05:44:56.684076+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:44:56.684096+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-01-13T05:44:56.684094+00:00 app[web.1]: > hex-chat@0.0.1 start /app
2015-01-13T05:44:56.684098+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:44:58.026967+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! hex-chat@0.0.1 start: `nod
e ./bin/www`
2015-01-13T05:44:58.027914+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-01-13T05:44:58.036635+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2015-01-13T05:44:58.027353+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2015-01-13T05:44:58.036330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2015-01-13T05:44:58.029530+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the hex-chat package,
2015-01-13T05:44:58.035643+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-01-13T05:44:58.035397+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2015-01-13T05:44:58.035862+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via
:
2015-01-13T05:44:58.036086+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls hex-chat
2015-01-13T05:44:58.037258+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2015-01-13T05:44:58.037538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
2015-01-13T05:44:58.036935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/.heroku/node
/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-01-13T05:44:58.037819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
2015-01-13T05:44:58.038761+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-01-13T05:44:57.983744+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/bin/www:16
2015-01-13T05:44:57.983628+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:44:57.988809+00:00 app[web.1]: app.set('port', port);
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991961+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (mod
ule.js:497:10)
2015-01-13T05:44:57.988819+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
56:26)
2015-01-13T05:44:58.030013+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991949+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no
method 'set'
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991964+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:929:3
2015-01-13T05:44:58.012736+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-01-13T05:44:58.044228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin
/www:16:5)
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991958+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:3
2)
2015-01-13T05:44:58.044612+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991956+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:474:10)
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991962+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2015-01-13T05:44:58.044010+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details
 can be found in:
2015-01-13T05:44:57.991959+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:312:12)
2015-01-13T05:44:58.043786+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-01-13T05:44:58.028349+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the hex-chat@0.0
.1 start script.
2015-01-13T05:44:58.795024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-13T05:44:58.805760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-01-13T05:45:03.195908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=hex-chat.herokuapp.com request_id=33cb8e2e-c056-4
b48-ac06-c4f33e611587 fwd="192.0.196.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byt
es=
2015-01-13T05:45:04.400880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=hex-chat.herokuapp.com request_id=0f0e55e7-62c0-4
981-ada8-598de3053b4a fwd="192.0.196.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byt
es=
```

edit*: I tried removing the bin folder and still no luck.

Comment: Between `bin/www` and `app.js`, there are two `http.Server`s being created that are both trying to `.listen()` to the same port. At most only one can succeed.

Comment: I deleted the bin folder and still no luck.